# Shrink a live, root filesystem on an IoT gadget?

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, iot

I have a Raspberry Pi 3, and its running a [Debian-lite image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). The device has 1 GB of RAM, but it has plenty of storage. It has plenty of storage because it *lacks* on-board eMMC, and it uses a sdCard which can be large (16 GB or 32 GB).

I'd like to add a swap file with a [small bit of swappiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness) to compensate for lack of RAM. To do that, I need to create a 1 GB swap file:

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        15G  1.4G   13G  10% /
devtmpfs        459M     0  459M   0% /dev
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           463M  6.2M  457M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   63M   21M   43M  33% /boot
```

I'm having trouble finding information on shrinking a live filesystem on a device that is headless and does not have a CD or DVD player (i.e., run Gparted). I've found similar procedures, like [How can I resize an ext root partition at runtime?](https://askubuntu.com/a/119458), but deleting the entire partition seems risky. Plus it does not work since there's no DOS partitions on an ext4 file system:

```
# sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0p2

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.25.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

/dev/mmcblk0p2: device contains a valid 'ext4' signature, it's strongly recommended to wipe the device by command wipefs(8) if this setup is unexpected to avoid possible collisions.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xfc95d188.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/mmcblk0p2: 14.8 GiB, 15861284864 bytes, 30979072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfc95d188
```

How do I shrink a live, root filesystem on an IoT gadget?

Comment: Maybe you can pop the SDcard in a Linux computer and resize from there?

Comment: @stresscool - attaching the microSD card to another computer worked well, and I was able to perform the resize. Now I need to do it on a BeagleBone with eMMC. The BeagleBone has 512 MB of RAM, and my compiler frequently dies because [cc1plus runs out of memory](https://www.google.com/search?q=cc1plus+out+of+memory) (one source file is a real monster).